# get only innerHTML value from an array of divs in javascript to build a calculator

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am new to JS, my plan is to build a simple calculator using 4 functions:

```
calculate();
getOperator();
getResults();
clearInputField();
```

However, I am struggling right at the beginning. I already converted my NodeList into an array. However, this array consists of Divs. I only want to get the innerHTML value of each index and pass this value to calculate. Would anyone be able to shed me some light on how could I achieve that?

```
let calcNumber = document.querySelectorAll("[data-number]");
let cellsArr = Array.prototype.slice.call(calcNumber);
let operatorsValue = document.querySelectorAll("[data-operator]");
let equal = document.getElementById("equal");



calcNumber.forEach((cell) => {
    cell.addEventListener("click", calculate);
});


// operatorsValue.forEach((opt) => {
//     opt.addEventListener("click", getOperator);
// });

// equal.addEventListener("click", getResults);

let value1;
let value2;
let results;

function calculate() {



}


---HTML--
<body>

    <div class='main-container'>
        <input>
        <div id="display"></div>
        <div data-firstValue class="firstValue"></div>
        <div data-secondValue class="secondValue"></div>
        <div class="calculator-container">
            <div data-number="0" class="cell">0</div>
            <div data-number="1" class="cell">1</div>
            <div data-number="2" class="cell">2</div>
            <div data-number class="cell">3</div>
            <div data-number class="cell">4</div>
            <div data-number class="cell">5</div>
            <div data-number class="cell">6</div>
            <div data-number class="cell">7</div>
            <div data-number class="cell">8</div>
            <div data-number class="cell">9</div>
            <div data-operator class="cell">+</div>
            <div data-operator class="cell">-</div>
            <div data-operator class="cell">x</div>
            <div data-operator class="cell">÷</div>
            <div id="equal" data-equals class="cell">=</div>
            <div data-delete class="cell">AC</div>
            <div data-singleDelete class="cell">←</div>
        </div>

        <script src="script1.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the text value of the clicked element using `innertext` property

In your code:

```
function calculate() {
    console.log(this.innerText);
}
```

If you need the complete HTML inside the clicked element then go with `innerHTML` property:

```
function calculate() {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
}
```

here `this` keyword will have context of clicked element.

Comment: appreciate that mate